# Changing only 2 bits of a byte (8051)

Tags: pointers, byte, microcontroller, bit, 8051

I am trying to make code that modifies two consecutive bits out of a byte using the fewest number of variables.

The memory is to be organized as follows:

```
aabbccdd eeffgghh iijjkkll mmnnoopp qqrrsstt uuvvwwxx
```

Each group of letters represents one byte and each letter represents a slot in which I can store a 2-bit value.

So far, I am able to come up with a partial answer since this code never writes new zero bits to the desired slot. Only ones.

```
  MEMORY equ 30h ;pointer to ram
  SLOTNO equ 8h  ;2-bit Slot unit we want

  mov A,#SLOTNO
  rrc A
  jnc noc
    xch A,R2
    rl A
    rl A
    xch A,R2
  noc:
  rrc A
  jnc noc2
    xch A,R2
    swap A
    xch A,R2
  noc2:
  add A,#MEMORY
  mov R1,A ;R1 = memory pointer + (slot # / 4)
  mov A,@R1
  orl A,R2 ;put the 2 bits in
  mov @R1,A
```

Is there any way I can do this without requiring a third memory byte (in this example, the third memory byte is register R2)?

And what's the easiest way to ensure that the correct 2-bit data is stored?

I am programming this for the AT89C4051 microcontroller and I'm running out of memory.

Comment: Please provide the *usage* of the code to be written, like some example calls. --- Are you aware of the bit-addressable space in internal RAM? Perhaps this will solve your issue.

Comment: Which memory is full? Code, SRAM or registers? @thebusybee: I think the 8051 knows indirect addressing only on byte level, not bitwise.

Comment: That's right, but the OP might not need it. For me it looks like an X-Y-problem that's why I ask for examples.